# django model column not appearing in postgre db on AWS

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, django-models

I have deployed a django app on heroku and I have connected postgre db on AWS. 
I have a Article model and columns like author, tile, Slug are all appearing in Postgre db except for the likes. It is appearing in the sqlite3 though. 
I added the Likes field recently and ran the makemigrations and migrate commands. But i am still facing the issue.

migrations file

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.5 on 2020-05-26 17:47

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Article',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('thumbnail', models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics')),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(default=None, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('likes', models.ManyToManyField(related_name='article_like', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='profile_pics')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=False, related_name='article_like')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]+'...'

    def getslug(self):
        bad_chars = [';', ':', '!', '*', '$','&','^','#','(','-',')']
        for char in bad_chars:
            if char in self.title:
                title = self.title.replace(char, '')
        return self.title.lower().replace(' ', '-')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Screenshot of columns appearing in the Postgre db.
[image]

Tables 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "likes" field is ManyToManyField, so Django does not create column in Article table, but one more table is created with 'user_id' and 'article_id' fields. So you should find a new table, not a new field. Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: Hi, I checked the tables and there is no table created with the user_id  and article_id fields. I keep getting this error when i try to access the likes api
"ProgrammingError at /articles/like/1
relation "articles_article_likes" does not exist"
I have updated the question with screenshot of the tables.